# Alignment of specific column in FPDF

Tags: fpdf

```
foreach ($fpdf as $reg){
$pdf->Row(array($i,$reg->T_REG_NO, $this->extrafn->titleCase($reg->T_NAME), $branch,$camp1,$camp2,$reg->T_STATE,$date));
}
```

First two columns should be middle aligned

```
------------------------------------------------------------
sl.| Reg.No | Name | Branch | camp1 | camp2 | State | Date
------------------------------------------------------------
1. | 1456   | afkj | CSE    | kmhuk | ahdoi | lkjha | 23.07.23
                              kloho | ghtrh | lhhig |
```

If camp1 and camp2 has two lines then other columns text value should be aligned in middle is there any solution?